# Error including static resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, twitter

I am working on a lightning component in my Salesforce Community. Yesterday it worked fine and out of the blue, I started getting the following error in the community builder. I am including the Twitter Widget js file in a static resource. I am also receiving the second error in the browser while visiting the page. Has anyone had issues like this before or with including a Twitter share button in their lightning components?

The full error messages I am receiving is:

```
Custom Script Eval error [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }]
```

and

```
Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,DOZENSOFRANDOMCHARS' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Comment: have you enabled any critical updates?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal we have not.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by a change that Salesforce made in Winter 19:

**Stricter CSP Restrictions**

> Stricter CSP disallows unsafe-inline for script-src. This means that
>   script tags can’t be used to load JavaScript, and event handlers can’t
>   use inline JavaScript.

You can disable this. Follow these steps:

Stricter CSP is enabled by default. To disable it:

1. From Setup, enter Session in the Quick Find box, and then select Session Settings.
2. Deselect the checkbox for “Enable Stricter Content Security Policy”.
3. Click Save.

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp_stricter.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response, upon looking at the page you linked I noticed:
 _The Lightning Component framework already uses Content Security Policy (CSP)_ 
I did deselect the checkbox which removed the refused to load script, however, the twitter script is still throwing the first error on the community builder.